# i am getting a templates error when hosting my django project at pythonanywhere

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates, pythonanywhere, django-settings

[This it the link to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpUSD.png)

```
I set path to templates and it’s working fine on my locally 

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [r'C:\Users\CODED\Desktop\direct-parcel-delivery-service\service\templates'],
```

View.py

```
def home(request):
         
    return render(request, 'service/home.html')
```

```
def Register(request):

    form = Packageform()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Packageform(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()                   
            
            return redirect('home')    
        else:
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        return render(request, 'service/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I will be very much grateful if anyone help me resolve this error

Comment: Path you are providing in your settings is a windows one on your local machine. On PythonAnywhere you run in Linux and path to your project must be different.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the error is warning you that the template as such does not exist. Do you have the path well done?

service/home.html

where do you have home.html located

y your settings.py try to put

```
'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    ],
```